# Unique ID generation Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

I have found an code in my project for generation of PKs and I simply cannot understand what this code do.

Can anyone give me some directions or ideas or explanation?

```
        Integer typecode = ((AbstractEntity)object).getTypeCode();//this is unique number for every type
        Long counter = Long.valueOf(this.fetchNextCounter(typecode.intValue())); //this returns a counter for each type 
        Integer clusterid = Integer.valueOf(0);
        Integer millicnt = Integer.valueOf(0);
        Long creationtime = Long.valueOf((new DateTime()).getMillis());
//here is where the magic starts and I cant simply understand a thing            
if(typecode.intValue() >= 0 && typecode.intValue() <= 32767) {
                long longValue = counter.longValue() << 15 | (long)typecode.intValue() << 48 & -281474976710656L;
                longValue += ((long)clusterid.intValue() & 15L) << 44 & 263882790666240L;
                longValue += creationtime.longValue() - 788914800000L << 4 & 17592186044400L;
                longValue += (long)(clusterid.intValue() >> 2) & 12L;
                longValue += (long)millicnt.intValue() & 3L;
                longValue &= -8796093022209L;

                return Long.valueOf(longValue);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("illegal typecode : " + typecode + ", allowed range: 0-" + 32767);
            }
```

I would appreciate everyone who can help? The problem we have is that we have typecodes which are bigger then 32767 and as the algorithm shows this doesn't work but why and how can we change it?

Answer (score 1):

Line by line (with added clarifying parentheses):

```
long longValue = counter.longValue() << 15 | (((long)typecode.intValue() << 48) & -281474976710656L);
```

It computes the binary-OR of two values:

- `counter` shifted left by 15 bits
- `typecode` shifted left by 48 bits and applied the mask `-281474976710656` (the same as `0xFFFF000000000000`). This mask seems redundant.

-

```
longValue += (((long)clusterid.intValue() & 15L) << 44) & 263882790666240L;
```

It gets the last 4 bits of of `clusterid` (`& 15`, same as `& 0xF`) , shifts it left by 44 bits, then applies the mask `263882790666240L`, that is the same as `0xF00000000000`. This last mask apply seems to be redundant. Sums it to the result.

```
longValue += ((creationtime.longValue() - 788914800000L) << 4) & 17592186044400L;
```

It subtracts the `creationtime` by 788914800000L (that is the timestamp for 12/31/1994 @ 11:00pm (UTC)), shifts 4 bits left, then applies the mask 17592186044400L, that is the same as 0xFFFFFFFFFF0. Sums it to the result.

```
longValue += (long)(clusterid.intValue() >> 2) & 12L;
```

Then it gets the cluster id, discards the last 2 bits (`>> 2`) and applies the mask `12L`, that is the same as getting the 3rd and 4th bits (5th and 6th in the original number). Sums it to the result.

```
longValue += (long)millicnt.intValue() & 3L;
```

It gets the last 2 bits of `millicnt` (`& 3L`). Sums it to the result.

```
longValue &= -8796093022209L;
```

Then it applies the the mask `-8796093022209L` to the reslt, that is the same as `0xFFFFF7FFFFFFFFFF`. It in practice zeroes the 44th bit of the resulting number.

Answer (score 0):

The operators <<, >>, | and & are all bitwise operators. The act on the individual bits of the underlying binary value of those numbers. For more information, give [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) article a read. And then take a sample value and work through the code.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code is putting parts of the bit representation of the typecode, counter, longvalue, creationtime, clusterid and millicnt after each other. This creates a new number that is unique because the combination of all the above is unique. However the way the values are packed in does mean that you can't have more then 32767 typecodes. There just isn't enough space.

You can see the process in detail by using `Long.toBinaryString()` to see the bit representations of the input and the longValue after each step.

Since these are primary keys for a database I reckon you can let the database generate the key for you though.